# Anonymous Thread not exceuting passed runnable's run method

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to threads and was going through some anonymous threads example

In my below program i am creating a runnable and passing it on to a anonymous thread. But when i am starting the thread it doesnot execute the run() method of the runnable i am passing. Please  correct me as where i am getting this wrong.

```
public class Anonymous {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Runnable task = new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Thread started");
            };
        };

        Anonymous1 ab = new Anonymous1();
        ab.setRunnableandStart(task); // passing runnable to other class


    }

}

public class Anonymous1 {
private Runnable runnable = null;

private Thread exeThread = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
 public void setRunnableandStart(Runnable runnable)
 {
     this.runnable = runnable; // setting the runnable
     exeThread = startExecution();
     System.out.println("Returned");
 }

 private Thread startExecution()
 {
      Thread ret = new Thread(runnable){

     };
     ret.start(); // starting the thread
     return ret;
 }
}
```

Comment: First thoroughly learn Java before you start with threads. Proper indentation of the source code helps, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
private Thread startExecution()
 {
     Thread ret = new Thread(runnable);
     ret.start(); // starting the thread
     return ret;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Thread ret = new Thread(runnable){

     };
```

to

```
Thread ret = new Thread(runnable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some `System.out.println (..)`'s to see what code is executing. Because it's not clear to me which `main` method is your actual entry point (you have two of them).. and one of them doesn't do anything.